# Find the maximum absolute value by row in an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, max, absolute, rowwise

I am hoping to find a vectorized approach to get the absolute maximum value from multiple columns in a data frame.

Basically is there an equivalent to the pmax function for getting absolute maximums.

```
test_df <- tibble(
  some_identifier = c("apple", "tunafish", "turkey_sandwich"), 
  val_a =  c(-1, 2, 0), 
  val_b = c(-3, 3, NA), 
  val_c = c(2, 3, 1)

)

# this is what abs_max column should be 
test_df$abs_max <- c(-3, 3, 1)
test_df

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  some_identifier val_a val_b val_c abs_max
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 apple              -1    -3     2      -3
2 tunafish            2     3     3       3
3 turkey_sandwich     0    NA     1       1
```

The abs_max column is what I want to create. A less than optimal solution may be to loop through each row; but wanted to reach out to identify possible a better method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way using `max.col` - thanks to @Gregor

```
f <- function(data) {
  tmp <- Filter(is.numeric, data)
  if(inherits(data, "tbl_df")) {
    tmp <- as.matrix(tmp)
  }
  tmp[cbind(1:nrow(tmp),
            max.col(replace(x <- abs(tmp), is.na(x), -Inf)))]
}

f(test_df)
# [1] -3  3  1
```

**step by step**

What we do is filter for numeric columns in the first step

```
Filter(is.numeric, test_df)
#  val_a val_b val_c
#1    -1    -3     2
#2     2     3     3
#3     0    NA     1
```

(called `tmp` in the function above)

Then

```
replace(x <- abs(Filter(is.numeric, test_df)), is.na(x), -Inf))
```

returns

```
#  val_a val_b val_c
#1     1     3     2
#2     2     3     3
#3     0  -Inf     1
```

that is a data.frame where `NA`s were replaced with `-Inf` and all negative values were replaced with their absolute value.

`max.col` returns the column position of the maximum values for each row

```
max.col(replace(x <- abs(Filter(is.numeric, test_df)), is.na(x), -Inf))
# [1] 2 2 3
```

This information is finally being used to extract the desired values from `Filter(is.numeric, test_df)` using a numeric matrix, i.e.

```
cbind(1:nrow(Filter(is.numeric, test_df)),
      max.col(replace(x <- abs(Filter(is.numeric, test_df)), is.na(x), -Inf)))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    2    2
#[3,]    3    3
```

**data**

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  some_identifier = c("apple", "tunafish", "turkey_sandwich"), 
  val_a =  c(-1, 2, 0), 
  val_b = c(-3, 3, NA), 
  val_c = c(2, 3, 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you - this is the type of practical solution I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the max.col function. Tibble's behavior is unexpected but good to know (I typically work in tidyverse). ```> mtcars[cbind(1:3, 4:6)]
[1] 110.00   3.90   2.32
> dplyr::as_tibble(mtcars)[cbind(1:3, 4:6)]
Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix. ```